# Is it possible to unit test ASP.NET 3.5 with the Visual Studio testing framework?

Tags: asp.net, .net, unit-testing

I'm not sure if I'm asking the right question.
If it isn't possible, is there an alternative to Visual Studio testing?

I ask this because I've read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182526%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) msdn tutorial, which seems made for 4.0 version.
For the test to work, you need to add:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.Web;
```

When I change the test project's framework target to 3.5, that `using` is not recognized.
VS is 2010.

Comment: Yes. What do you find missing with the built-in testing? What version of VS are you using?

Comment: NUnit is a common testing framework for .NET if you're unsatisfied with the built-in stuff: http://www.nunit.org/

Comment: @NWard I've read that Nunitasp exists, but I'm not sure if it works the same way.

Comment: @Erandros UNitASP was designed for acceptance testing, not unit tests. NUnit can unit test the entirety of ASP.NET without issue - your question makes me wonder what kind of tests you're intending to write?

Comment: @NWard you hit it right in the nail. At work, my boss told me "I don't know what is unit testing, do it for our asp.net project". That's the only thing he said to me. There's a lot work being done in the background because of the way the project is configured, I don't even know what am I supposed to test. I'll keep NUnit in mind though, thanks.

Comment: Unit Testing is an art/science in and of itself, and is very rewarding (and does wonderful things for your code!) I wish you the best of luck in pursuing it. Asking specific questions about unit testing on Stack Overflow will be helpful to you as well.